# Can we change the color of the wordcloud to make it darker in python? Can wordcloud export the frequency as a dataframe?

Tags: python, colors, word-cloud

There are some words which are hard to visualize due to their super bright color. Does anyone know how to change the color tone in the "wordcloud"? I am wondering whether the wordcloud can export the relative frequency of the word to .csv?

```
wordcloud2 = WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords, background_color="white",width=1800, height=1000,max_words=200,collocations=False,
                      relative_scaling = 0.2).generate(text2)
plt.imshow(wordcloud2, interpolation='bilinear')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)
plt.savefig('03_processed_translated_2020_wordcloud.tiff', dpi=300, format='tiff', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the color palette of words with 'colormap' parameter.

```
# Libraries
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a list of words
text=("Python Python Python Matplotlib Matplotlib Seaborn Network Plot Violin Chart Pandas Pandas Numpy Artificial Intelligence Machine Learning Internet Of Things Scikit-Learn")

# create the wordcloud object
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=480, height=480, colormap="Blues").generate(text)

# display the generated image:
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.margins(x=0, y=0)
plt.show()
```

Try and let me know if it meets your requirement.

Comment: @ UtkarshPal-MT - Thanks, it works. By the way, I understand that the word size reflects the frequency but how about the color shade? Does the color shade have the meaning.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try shading in wordcloud. Although, you can refer this link https://towardsdatascience.com/standing-out-from-the-cloud-how-to-shape-and-format-a-word-cloud-bf54beab3389, might be helpful.